# make: *** No rule to make target 'run-service-development' called from docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile

I have the following files

```
--docker
|    |---docker-compose.yml
|    |---Dockerfile
|
|----Makefile
|---run.py
```

The docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3'
services:
  ml_api:
    build:
      context: ../
      network: host
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"   # expose webserver to localhost host:container
    command: bash -c "make run-service-development"
```

and the Makefile

```
# Specify phony list to ensure make recipes do not conflict with real file names
.PHONY: run-service-development

# start up Flask API service
run-service-development:
    @echo "+ $@"
    python run.py
```

When I do `docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --build` I get the containers but in the end I got the error

```
✔ Network docker_default     Created                                                                                                               0.2s 
 ✔ Container docker-ml_api-1  Created                                                                                                               0.1s 
Attaching to docker-ml_api-1
docker-ml_api-1  | make: *** No rule to make target 'run-service-development'.  Stop.
```

But the rule is right there!

What could be happening here and how to fix it?

EDIT:

I debugged and the reason why this is happening is because the current directory is `/`
which is strange because the Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# ensure we can run the make commands
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y make && \
    apt-get install -y libffi-dev gcc && \
    # for swagger
    apt-get install -y curl

RUN pip install -r /opt/app/requirements.txt
COPY Makefile /opt/app/Makefile
COPY api /opt/app/api
COPY run.py /opt/app/run.py
WORKDIR /opt/app
```

and the last line is supposed to change the directory to `/opt/app` where the Makefile is.

Why is this WORKDIR command not working?

Comment: Most likely the directory you think you're in is not the directory you're really in and that makefile is not accessible to make.  You can use `make -f Makefile` and make will give an error if it can't find the makefile (if you just run `make` alone and it can't find the makefile is just uses its own internal database of rules).  Alternatively you can add an invocation of `pwd` to your bash script before invoking make to see what the working directory is, and/or add `ls` to see what the contents of the directory are.  All these are simple debugging steps you can take, that don't require SO.

Comment: I did and yes the directory is `/`. The questions are, that is inside the container? why? and how can this be corrected?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  But in any event, it's a docker question and I don't know much about docker and docker compose, so you'll have to figure that out with help from someone else.  If you can't, obviously you can just add a `cd` operation before the make invocation, or use `make -C /opt/app` or whatever.